# UDP Handshake and Data exchange between Client and Server

Tags: sockets, udp

**Handshake:**

- Client --> SNK? --> Server
- Server --> YES --> Client, 
  Handshake stays that way and works perfectly.

  ```
  if ((recvMsgSize = recvfrom(sock,  recBuffer, RX_BUF_SIZE, 0,(struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, &cliAddrLen)) < 0)

  printf("Handling Client: %s\n", inet_ntoa(clntAddr.sin_addr));

  printf("Received:");
  for(i = 0; recBuffer[i] != '\0'; ++i)
      printf("%c",recBuffer[i]);
  printf("\n");

  /* Send response datagram back to the client */
  unsigned char respBuffer[] = {255, 255, 255, 255, 4, 'Y', 'E', 'S'};
  if (sendto(sock,  respBuffer, sizeof(respBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) & clntAddr, sizeof(clntAddr)) < 0)
  ```

**Then**

- Client --> Query (For instance, SELECT ID from sensors) --> Server
- Server --> Query result --> Client

Is it possible to use recvfrom() and sendto() again? (As we already using for handshake) or any other way to handle like thread or fork? 
Thank you!

Comment: Note: your loop condition `recBuffer[i] != '\0'` is wrong. The received message is not necessarily nul-terminated.

Comment: You can use both as many times as you like, but remember that packet arrival, order, and non-duplication are not guaranteed in UDP.